# Querying the min element using LINQ inside Tasks

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm kinda new to LINQ and so I struggle with the predicates and hence I need your help.
I have a parent task which returns me a collection ex: a list, `List<CSample>`. The object can basically be represented as below:

```
public class CSample
{
        public double Distance { get; set; }
        public double XPosition { get; set; }
        public double Error { get; set; }
}
```

Coming to my parent task, I have to continue with the processing of the CSample collection items once all my child tasks are done executing.

```
Task<List<CSample>> parent = new Task<List<CSample>>(() =>
 {

  results = new List<CSample>(); // list to store results
  //.. processing of child tasks in parallel
  return results;

  });
```

And so my parent task continues with other processing (i.e. in this case finding the item where **Error** value is the least.)

```
var cwt = parent.ContinueWith
                (p =>
                        {
                            if (p.Result != null && p.Result.Count > 0)
                            {
                               CSample processedData = (CSample )(p.Result.OrderBy(s => s.Error).FirstOrDefault());                              
                            }
                        }
                 );
```

However, My application throws an object null reference exception at this line, **s is null**

```
CSample processedData = (CSample )(p.Result.OrderBy(s => s.Error).FirstOrDefault());
```

Is this the correct way I'm using Predicates for finding the item with minimum Error value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only interested in one element (presumably a non-null element) so try filtering out null values before calling OrderBy:

```
CSample processedData = (CSample)(p.Result
    .Where(s => s != null)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Error)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

That will guarantee that s.Error can not produce a null reference exception, as s will never be null.

Comment: Thanks that was quick and works ! I just didn't know I could do that this way